# $(window).load(handler) won't fire

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, load

I´ve been working with on a Asp.NET web app using jQuery to generate a sweet , flexible and fast UI. I´ve created the skeleton

```
<div id='title'>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <h3 class='color-black h3'>
        Choose the career</h3>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id='tabbedContent' class='tabbed_content'>
    <div id='tabs' class='tabs'>
        <div class='moving_bg'>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='contentID' class='slide_content'>
        <div id='tabsliderID' class='tabslider'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now onStart I will append some dynamically created DOM elements using jQuery. I do this by calling two js functions from the Page_Load method (ASP) that will do all the magic . Then I'll need to init a couple of scripts (tabbedContent and iNettuts). 
The thing is that those scripts need to be initialized only after the whole page is created -including the dynamically created content- so i CANT use $(document).ready and when I use $(window).load sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

I´ve been googling it for at least two weeks and still nothing. What should I do? Isn't jQuery supposed to handle this issues? and if not .. is there any workaround?

ps. Tryin' to make it work in IE7-8, Chrome 10 and FF 6

BTW, once I achieve this i´ll need to do some web services calls to get data from the db. Will this affect the behavior ? Should I expect more headaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a bit of research on your suggestions and a very very long night implementing Radus suggestion -which could be interpreted as flags for each element to be loaded- I started to ask myself : what if ready() has a flag? in that case I shouldn't worry about the timing of the initialization. Well, turns out that this flag ,indeed, exists and it's called holdReady().
Basically, it prevents the ready() event to be launched until the flag is set to false.

"The $.holdReady() method allows the caller to delay jQuery's ready event. This advanced feature would typically be used by dynamic script loaders that want to load additional JavaScript such as jQuery plugins before allowing the ready event to occur, even though the DOM may be ready. This method must be called early in the document, such as in the  immediately after the jQuery script tag. Calling this method after the ready event has already fired will have no effect."[1]

So, I did:

```
$.holdReady(true); 
//using ASPs page_load so it will be triggered everytime 
//a postback happens -gonna need it for the AJAX requests i'm planning to do.
//Then I create the dynamic content
$.holdReady(false); //then I let the event fire


$(document).ready(function(){
  //append the dynamic content
  iNettuts.init();
  tabbedContent.init();
});
```

And that's it, problem solved. Hope this helps someone else, and thank you all.

[1] http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this, it looks great! You should accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Page_Load` will work fine for your .ready handler.  If you need true dynamic DOM events you should use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for your event binding.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
    String csname1 = "PageStartUpScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
    {
        StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
        cstext1.Append(@"$(document).ready(function() {
                                // add your startup.init functions here
                              });");

        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready(handler)` is the correct form.  You can also just do `$(handler)`

The `.load` method is done on elements and is actually used to load the HTML response from an XHR call into an element.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be calling the javascript functions from .Net in the Page_Load handler (though of course this is possible).

Instead, put all your jQuery functionality inside `$(document).ready()`. Then it will be executed once the page loads and is ready to accept dynamic manipulation via JavaScript. This is especially important for IE6 compatibility, as it will choke if you try and alter the DOM before the page has finished loading.

So, in your case, your jQuery javascript code might look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // create your dynamic content here
    tabbedContent();
    iNettuts();
});
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting startup scripts in Page_Load, it all gets rendered together.  You have multiple .ready functions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(document).load` instead.

Comment: why the vote down when someone answered the same thing with a vote up?

Comment: +1 $(document).load() is isn't what the OP needs, but no need to be down-voted for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

OR try `$(document).ready()` instead

Comment: The OP just said that `$(document).ready()` doesn't do what he needs... He needs things to happen after some dynamic content is loaded, which happens *after* the document is ready.

Comment: Probably because he isn't using it right, $(document).ready() works like a charm.

Comment: @rick schott, the document is ready as soon as all DOM elements have been rendered. If then you proceed to load the content of these elements via AJAX and populate them, this happens *after* the DOM is rendered, and thus *after* the document is ready.

Comment: I know that, that is where .live comes into play, however that has nothing to with getting startup/init functions to fire.

Comment: @rick schott, I agree with `live()`, but again, it doesn't seem to be what he's looking for. Think about a scenario in which you need to populate 10 divs with data, and _after_ all of them are populated, run some code. You would need to find out when they all finish populating, and `live()` wouldn't help in this case.

Comment: Yes it will, if you bind with .live, when the elements come into the DOM the elements become live, that is the point of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4375/discussion-between-rick-schott-and-radu)

Comment: @rickschott I agree that $(WINDOW).load() is not the right answer -basically because it isn't working - but y already tried  $(document).ready() ; in fact it was my first choice two weeks ago, but it didn't work as expected so I tried $(WINDOW).load() Radu is right , I need to create some divs -and other stuff- and then (after they're created and populated ) run some scripts -basically turn them into widgets and add a tabbed interface- .

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `$(document).ready()` function, you could create a hash with the dynamic objects that need to load as keys and their ready states as values. Once each dynamic object finishes loading, you set its value to true. You can then poll to see when all the values are true, and execute the code you need when that happens.

`$(window).load()` sometimes works and sometimes doesn't because sometimes it happens for all the elements to load fast enough for them to be ready when your code runs.